# PHP Secure data in the folder above the root folder

Tags: php, php-7, php-5.3

Which way is the best to store and address all files which contain security data like sql password and username in the folder above the root folder?[image: The picture shows the current folder structure]
Is there a way to have autoloader.php and a php require query automatically enter all this data in the parent folder?

Comment: try and put all your PHP BEFORE your HTML. If you don't, you'll never be able to header or start sessions etc, since headers will already have been sent, and content is now being rendered. In the HTML try to stick to just looping and echoing.

Comment: so long as your config files aren't in a publically accessible folder of your webbsite, you should be fine. So don't put it in public.

Comment: @delboy1978uk I know I can’t put the files in my Public folder. But I wanted to know how to simplify the implementation so that I don’t have to make new include command for each file.

Comment: Make a bootstrap.php, and put all the common startup stuff in there, db connection etc. Then you only need to include one file which is a lot less hassle

Comment: It's highly recommended to not store credentials in PHP files. Instead set them as environment variables and access them in parts of the code you need them in ensuring you never reveal them in any HTML page. Take a look at [dotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) for a library that allows you to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can do something to this effect...

```
foreach(glob('path_to_folder/*') as $path)
  include $path;
```